# Knockout JS: Dynamic tabs with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Requirement:

On my html side I have 2 tables containing data whose data can be dynamic. Users can press save to save the data to the db. This all has been setup and works fine.
Now as an additional requirement this all html data needs to be moved into tabs. 
There is a button on click of which another tab needs to be created with the same content. Clicking again the same tab creates another tab with the content.

I havent used tabs and templates before so not sure how to handle this dynamic content. I tried to move my existing code which was working into tabs. It creates tab but my content inside the tab now doesnt works. Currently I have set it up for static tabs. But I am looking to create dynamic tabs and data on button click.

Here is the same jsfiddle which I was able to setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/p7fu8pmm/13/

Below is the sample code for my tabs:

```
<div id="tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
  <div class="tab" data-bind="css: {selected: $parent.selectedTab() == id()}, 
text: name, click: $parent.selectedTab.bind($parent, id())"></div>
</div>
```

Again this is 4 static tabs which I was able to create one.

Could someone work on my jsfiddle and help me get started.

Comment: Check your console... you've got some errors in there.

Comment: @JasonSpake So thats one of the issue. If I dont have tabs and my tab content div is outside it runs fine. When inside the tab content it throws me error. I was already doing $parent on the observables if you see.

Comment: @JasonSpake I have updated my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ksingh24/z0mqrgxt/10/ . There are no errors now. The tab one is loaded with data fine. What I am looking for is to make this dynamic. So when the user clicks Add Tab button at the bottom it adds one more tab with all the data shown in tab1 currently and so on.

Comment: Do you want the new tab to literally point to the same data as the first tab or to a copy of the data? The way you have it right now it's not a copy but sharing the same data between tabs so if you change a field on tab 4, the same field on tab 1 will also change.

Comment: Jason, I want the first tab data to act as a template. So first time the come to the page they click on add tab it adds 2 tables that I have and the user can save data by adding rows etc. The next time they come, they could click on add tab it would again create a template of that data (empty) so that the user can add rows etc depending on their needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab needs to have its own copy of the data or modifying it in one tab will modify it in all tabs. The first thing you should do is move your `items` and `employee` arrays onto the tab object (and update the bindings accordingly). When you initialize a new tab you want the data to come from a template array of items, but each tab creates its own copy.

```
self.templateItems = [{
      id: "1",
      firstName: "Bob",
      lastName: "Hen"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      firstName: "Henry",
      lastName: "Arman"
    }
  ];

self.Tab = function(id, name, text, selected) {
  var tab = this;
  tab.id = ko.observable(id);
  tab.name = ko.observable(name);
  tab.text = ko.observable(text);
  tab.items = ko.observableArray(self.templateItems.slice()); //create a copy of the template array
  tab.employee = ko.observableArray([]);

  tab.add = function() {
    tab.employee.push(new Employee());
  };

  tab.remove = function(data) {
    tab.employee.remove(data);
  };
  return tab;
};
```

Then adding a new tab dynamically isn't much different from adding the original 4.

```
self.Save = function() {
  self.tabs.push(new self.Tab(self.tabs().length+1, 'New Tab', 'dynamically added tab'));
};
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7fu8pmm/53/)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I will look to integrate this and let you know. One question though. The line  tab.items = ko.observableArray(self.templateItems.slice()); //create a copy of the template array .  Why the slice has not been used for employee array. And also why in the Add function we are just pushing Employee and not Item

Comment: @aman I don't fully understand what your code is trying to do so I wasn't sure what your intention was for the employee array. It can be done the same way if it also has a template source array.

Comment: Got it now. I will work on this to integrate with my code and post separate ques if needed.

Comment: One quick thing. I have integrated this with my requirement. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksingh24/fgszddLp/  The only issue I am facing here is that when I create a new tab, the values/data from previous tab is copied over to new one. What I want is everything to be empty as in initial state. So if you see the fiddle. and click on add new tab, it created empty data for the 2 tables. Thats what I want everytime a new tab is created. But if you add rows to the table and enter some values. You can see those values copied over to new tab. What am I missing here.

Comment: @aman You said you wanted the first tab data to act as a template. Copying that data was the whole point of making the template array and using slice() to copy its data. If you don't want the data there on the new tab then just get rid of the starting template.

Comment: Jason i understood that having template and slice() made a copy so thats why I removed that before. See my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ksingh24/fgszddLp/  But its still making copies

Comment: @aman You didn't just remove that part you removed all of the code that made the tabs work. Go back to my example fiddle and look at how the data is stored on the tab object not at the root.

Comment: Jason there were issues trying to integrate initial code that you had shared with mine. So I had modified that to fit my existing one. Everything works fine, the tabs are created. Its just that the data is copied over. Wouldnt it be possible to make it work with my code. If not then I will have to see how else I can integrate this.