# JS event listener not working on div after knockout conditional

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, knockout.js, event-listener

In a `.cshtml` file (razor page from .NET), I have a partial HTML element under a knockout conditional :

```
<!-- ko with: key -->
    <div class="..." style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: condition, if: condition">
        ...
        @Html.Partial("OtherHTMLFile")
        ...
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

In the other HTML file (the `OtherHTMLFile`), I have listeners on a div that tracks the changes:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        ...
    }

    var myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div');
    myDiv.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {        <---- The part that doesn't work
        <content here to be executed>
    }
}

<div id="my-div">
    ...
</div>
```

If the page loads (or refreshed) with `condition` set to true, then everything works as expected - the event listener listens to `myDiv` from the partial HTML file and the content under the listener's function will be executed whenever a wheel action is detected. However, if a tab (from the same page) with `condition` is false is first loaded, then switched to a tab with `condition` set to true, the event listener on `myDiv` would fail to work (no wheel actions will be detected).

The event listener for keyup on the document works fine in both cases.

I'm not very experienced in these stuff and I can't seem to figure out a way to fix this (where the event listener works on `myDiv` even after the first tab loads with `condition` set to false and then the tab with `consition` set to true). I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577554/knockout-js-dynamic-tabs-with-dynamic-content

Comment: yes, because your element is "not existing in DOM on document ready" then - alternative: use `data-bind="event: {'wheel' : yourfunction()}"` on the element